# vectorized expression to rbind a list of dataframes?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate question, but I can't find anything on this in the stack overflow archives.

I wrote a function that returns a zoo object (makeTrace1). In a second function (make2DHist), I call this function many times and so generate a list of dataframes (converted from the returned zoo objects). I would then like to rbind all these dataframes in my list together. I can rbind specific elements together so I could do this with a for loop, **but is there a vectorized expression to rbind all the dataframes in the list together?**

Here's my code:

```
make2DHist <- function()
{

    v = list()
      times=4

    for(i in 1:times)
    {
        vv = makeTrace1()
        v[[i]] = data.frame(Date=time(vv), vv, check.names = FALSE, row.names=NULL) 

    } 

    hhh = rbind(v[[1]], v[[2]]) <-----this works
    hhh2 = rbind(v[c(1:4)]) <-this does not work


}
m= make2DHist()
```

Comment: I would go with `do.call("rbind", lst)` or using the `data.table` package `rbindlist(lst)`

Comment: @user20650 I knew I was forgetting something. Many thanks!

Comment: @Henrik Thank you, but this is probably not a duplicate. That question was a question of how to flatten a list. This question was about how to vectorize an rbind. I read that question before posting this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> x <- do.call(rbind, your_list_of_matrices_or_data_frames_here)
```

Comment: Also look at `rbind.fill` in the (very useful) `plyr` package.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to R so these suggestions are really helpful.